Max-min and min-Max relationship in ZeroSum Games
In the attached Zero Sum Game, I have solved for two Mixed Nash Equilibrium, $(l,m)$ and $(m,r.)$

In $(l,m)$, the payoff is $8/5$ to $P_1$, and $-8/5$ to $P_2$. Here,  $P_1$ mixes between Top and Bottom with probability $4/5$ and $1/5$ respectively. $P_2$ mixes between left and middle with probability $3/5$ and $2/5$ respectively.

In $(m,r)$ the payoff is $5/2$ to $P_1$ and $-5/2$ to $P_2$. Here  player 1 mixes between Top and Bottom with probability $1/2$ each. And Player two mixes between middle and right with probability $1/4$ and $3/4$ respectively.


I am confused about how these equilibriums relate to each players max-min and min-max strategy and Von Neumann's Minimax theorem. And the theorems of Zero-sum games more generally.
Questions

How do the Mixed Nash Equilibriums relate to Player 1's Min-Max and Max-Min Strategy
How do the Mixed Nash Equilibriums relate to Player 2's Min-Max and Max-Min Strategy
How does this game illustrate the relationship found in zero sum games, between players Min-Max and Max-Min Strategy.
How does this game illustrate Von Neumann's Minimax theorem.


